# Vim-substitute command inserts duplication

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I was stumbling over a behaviour in Vim's `substitute`-command that I can't
really follow:

Given the following line of code that contains the `&&` sequence I wanted to
substitute the `&&` with `&&` and a newline:

```
return a && b
```

In my first try I simply used `s/&& /&&^M/g` (`^M` was inserted via `Ctrl-V
<Enter>`).
This results in the following code:

```
return a && && 
b
```

How exactly is the substitution performed to insert the second `&&<space>`?
I expected the first (and only match) to be `&&<space>` and this complete match to be
substituted by `&&^M`?

The question is not about how to perform the correct substitution - I ended up
using the `\zs` token to reset the start of the match and only insert the
newline.
I just want to understand why exactly the duplication is introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're hitting is that the substitute command treats `&` as a special token in the replacement to mean the matched text. You need to escape it.

```
:s/&& /\&\&^M/g
```

Comment: Ah that explains why `s/&& /and&M/g` DID work. Maybe I should just print out `:h regex` as a reference.

Comment: @Gjallar: Under nomagic mode `&` becomes a normal character. However, I'm not sure how to turn on nomagic mode for the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This simple command should work, leaving an inelegant trailing space on the first line:

```
:s/&& /&\r
```

But I don't like trailing spaces.

This one does what you want without leaving a trailing space:

```
:s/&&\zs /\r
```

I use `&&` as a "marker", the actual match, a `<space>`, is delimited with `\zs` and is replaced by a carriage return.

See `:help \zs`.

***edit***

Ho crap, I completely failed to read the last paragraph of your question.